# How to check that text was selected in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have simple JTextField and KeyListener.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

@Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
   {
   }

   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
   }

   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {
      validateThatTextWasSelectedWithShiftAndArrow();
   }
});
```

How do I check that someone select text with key combination (SHIFT + LEFT or RIGHT ARROW) ?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could customise the key-bindings or simple use `JTextField#getSelectedText` or `JTextField#getSelectionStart` and `JTextField#getSelectionEnd`.  Oh, and `KeyListener` is a really horrible idea generally, but especially with text components

Comment: Is it possible to check if KeyEvent is combination of key shift and arrow ?

Comment: @ThirdMartian What you're not taking into consideration is not all systems use the same key combinations.  FKY, the key bindings you probably want are `selection-backward` and `selection-forward`

Comment: You may want to have a look at CaretListener instead .

Answer (score 2):

Swing makes heavy use of the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to make it easy to work with existing functionality.  We already know the `JTextField` is fully capable of performing selection, we just need to be able to plug into it.

The `JTextField` uses the `selection-backward` and `selection-forward` to execute the required functionality when the system dependent key strokes are activated, we just need to inject our code into it.

For this, I wrote a simple `ReplaceAction` action, which takes the old `Action` we are interested, and calls two methods, one before and one after the old `Action` is called.  This allows you to inject your required functionality into whatever point is required to achieve whatever functionality you are trying to implement...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MonitorSelection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MonitorSelection();
    }

    public MonitorSelection() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            add(field);
            InputMap im = field.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
            ActionMap am = field.getActionMap();

            Action oldAction = am.get("selection-backward");
            am.put("selection-backward", new ReplacedAction(oldAction){
                @Override
                protected void doAfterReplacedAction() {
                    System.out.println("Before selection-backward");
                }

                @Override
                protected void doBeforeReplacedAction() {
                    System.out.println("After selection-backward");
                }

            });
            oldAction = am.get("selection-forward");
            am.put("selection-forward", new ReplacedAction(oldAction){
                @Override
                protected void doAfterReplacedAction() {
                    System.out.println("Before selection-forward");
                }

                @Override
                protected void doBeforeReplacedAction() {
                    System.out.println("After selection-forward");
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class ReplacedAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Action replaced;

        public ReplacedAction(Action replaced) {
            this.replaced = replaced;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            doBeforeReplacedAction();
            replaced.actionPerformed(e);
            doAfterReplacedAction();
        }

        protected void doBeforeReplacedAction() {
        }

        protected void doAfterReplacedAction() {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it could help, probably  because I didn't explain correctly. What I'm doing is calling method when KeyReleased. And I want to prevent calling this method when these keys are selection keys, because my method stops selecting.

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't be using a `KeyListener` with text component in the first place, it's the wrong way to interact with text components. What is this "method" doing which is resetting the selection?

Comment: The problem is I have to use KeyListener. This method is updating my data and after that is setting caret to end of text, so it is stopping selecting text.

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` to monitor for changes to the text field, use `DocumentFilter` to filter content coming into the field

Comment: As I said, I have to use KeyListener.

Comment: I don't see why, it's not the appropriate mechanism for dealing with text components